# Kotlin Kmongo library with abstract class collection

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, kmongo

I have these models

```
abstract class Message : Data
data class TextMessage(val m: String): Message
data class ImageMessage(val m: ByteArray): Message
```

and I want to get a collection by the abstract class Message

```
database.getCollection<Message>
```

But it will actually be a implement class (TextMessage, ImageMessage) instance depending on it's content

```
when(val value = collection.findOne()) {
    is TextMessage -> {}
    is ImageMessage -> {}
}
```

how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The KMongo library has 3 options for object mapping, and your solution will depend on which one is being used.

> By default, Jackson engine is used. You can use POJO Codec engine by adding a -native suffix to the artifactId, or Kotlinx Serialization by adding a -serialization suffix to the artifactId.

https://litote.org/kmongo/quick-start/#object-mapping-engine

Depending on the engine used, apply how that engine handles polymorphism:

- Jackson

  ```
  @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)
  abstract class Message
  ```

  more info: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization
- Native

  ```
  @BsonDiscriminator
  abstract class Message
  ```

  not sure if there is much more info on this but the official doc here: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.3/bson/pojos/#annotations

  this essentially stores the class name under a `_t` field and gets used during deserialization
- kotlinx serialization

  ```
  @Serializable
  sealed class Message
  @Serializable
  data class TextMessage(val m: String) : Message()
  @Serializable
  data class ImageMessage(val m: ByteArray) : Message()
  ```

  Like jackson, there's other ways and things you may want to consider here: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/polymorphism.md

Comment: I have added the @BsonDiscriminator annotation, and have done other thing like registering codec, but it is still not working. the kmongo official website document is not so clear enough for me

Comment: @user16799920 can you share your kmongo dependency or project? I had tried out all 3 before answering. The `@BsonDiscriminator` will only work if you are using `-native` dependency. Registering a codec should not be necessary unless there's something in `Data` class that we're not seeing.

Comment: It turns out that I was not using the -native dependency. Genuinely sorry for my carelessness